# Can't figure out what this is? Unrecognized escape sequence (Mono)

Tags: c#, .net, mono

So I was poking around some code and I saw this:

```
    static void ReadArguments(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i += 2)
        {
            switch (args[i - 1])
            {
            case "-config":
                Config.Initialize(args[i]);
                break;
            default:
                Log.Message(LogType.Error, "'\{args[i - 1]}' isn't a valid argument.");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!Config.IsInitialized)
            Config.Initialize("./Configs/Config.conf");
    }
```

What I'm referring to is "'\{args[i - 1]}' isn't a valid argument." for the Log.Message function, its a normal string but I've never seen this '\{args[i - 1]}' before, when I compile it in mono it errors out with an unrecognized escape sequence, but with .net it compiles fine.

Does anyone have a name for this/can point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new feature in C# 6.0 specification which is great substitute for `String.Format` and dirty ways of string concatenations (using `string.concat` or `+`)

Read more: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540869

You may be compiling with older version of compiler, hence the compilation error.